# Помесить несколько методов на одно событие Vue js

Tags: javascript, vue.js

В форме есть поле:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" :class="{ 'is-invalid': $v.firstName.$error }" id="firstName" v-model="firstName" @blur="$v.firstName.$touch">
```

при изменении этого поля кроме `$v.firstName.$touch` также должен вызываться еще метод `changeFirstName`
так же `@blur="changeFirstName"`

При этом `changeFirstName` - кастомный метод, а `$v.firstName.$touch` нет

Как вызвать несколько событий?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Создать метод обработчик события, который будет вызывать остальные обработчики

```
<input type="text" v-model="firstName" @blur="onFirstNameInputBlur($event)">
```

...

```
methods: {

    onFirstNameInputBlur(event) {
        this.handle1(event);
        this.handle2(event);
        ...
    }

}
```

Или создать пользовательское событие и обработчики для него программно

```
<input type="text" v-model="firstName" @blur="$emit('firstname-input-blur', $event)">
```

...

```
mounted: function() {
    this.$on('firstname-input-blur', function(event) {
        ...
    });
    this.$on('firstname-input-blur', function(event) {
        ...
    });
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Привяжитесь к `@change` или `@input` и вызывайте любой метод, либо навешивайте `watch` на `firstName`